# Search, cart and category not working on product page

Tags: magento-1, product-page

I have a problem with this shop: [www.phone-parts.dk](http://www.phone-parts.dk)

The search function, cart and category works fine, when a customer is watching the products from a category, but when he/she clicks and enters the product page, they stop working. They are there, but nothing happens when you click it.
The cart won't drop down and the search bar wont show. Specially on mobile devices. On mobile devices the category drop-down menu, wont work either.

Any of you guys have an idea of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have a js error on the product page:

[image: Error]

You are adding jquery twice. You should remove the second jQuery inclusion.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phone-parts.dk/skin/frontend/default/theme262k/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phone-parts.dk/skin/frontend/default/theme262k/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phone-parts.dk/skin/frontend/default/theme262k/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phone-parts.dk/skin/frontend/default/theme262k/js/scripts.js"></script>
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phone-parts.dk/js/ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js"></script>
<!-- Remove next line -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phone-parts.dk/js/mirasvit/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phone-parts.dk/js/mirasvit/core/underscore.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

You should search the second jQuery inclusion inside the layout files of the mirasvit core module. It should look like this: `<action method="addJs"><script>mirasvit/core/jquery.min.js</script></action>`

Perhaps this link from Mirasvit will help you: [What to do if I have two jQuery libs on the page](https://mirasvit.com/doc/hdmx/1.2.3/known_issues/two_jquery)

> If your store uses own jQuery, you may need to disable jQuery used by
>   Helpdesk.
>
> To do this, please, remove the line
>
> ```
>  <action method="addJs"><script>mirasvit/core/jquery.min.js</script></action>
> ```
>
> from the following files:
>
> ```
> /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mst_helpdesk.xml
> /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mst_helpdesk.xml
> ```
>
> and clear the Magento cache.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not a master of magento, so could you tell me which file i should remove it from?

Comment: @AlexH.Andersen Try to find the "core/jquery.min.js" string in your project.

Comment: @AlexH.Andersen I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the problem. It was a bad jquery from a lighbox addon. Uninstall and all works perfect! Have a nice one!